# What are partials in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how partials works in rails.

Here is code :

```
<%= render "layouts/appended_pages", pages: {partial: "items",
                                             collection: @results,
                                             locals: {user_flag: false}} %>
```

I understand that this render will render _appended_pages but what will do part with pages:  ? how it works

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: I read that guide , but still can figure out what meanas pages:

Comment: @Ivan: it's a parameter. The partial `appended_pages` will have a local variable defined, `pages` which will hold a hash.

Answer (score 1):

Partials allow you to easily organize and reuse your view code in a Rails application. Partial filenames typically start with an underscore ( _ ) and end in the same .html.erb extension as your views. It helps so you dont have to re-write your code over and over